# Como criar pesquisa no MySQL que retorne linhas sem correspondência?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma pesquisa que retorne os registros que não fazem parte da condição da pesquisa.

Por exemplo, pense na situação onde exista um banco de dados de uma locadora de filmes com a tabela `cliente` e a tabela `aluguel`. A tabela `cliente` tem uma tupla `cliente_id` e a tabela `aluguel` tem uma tupla `cliente_id`.

O que eu quero é ver o nome dos clientes que nunca alugaram um filme, ou seja, queria que minha consulta retornasse todos os nomes que não satisfizerem o script abaixo:

```
`select first_name, last_name from customer
inner join rental on customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id;`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta usar um `LEFT JOIN`, e verificar quais relações retornam nulo:

```
SELECT nome, filme_id
   FROM cliente
   LEFT JOIN aluguel ON cliente.cliente_id = aluguel.cliente_id
   WHERE aluguel.cliente_id IS NULL;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8c937/1)**.

**Explicação:**

O `LEFT JOIN` faz com que todos os valores da tabela da esquerda retornem, tendo ou não um valor correspondente na da direita.

Assim, o `WHERE aluguel.cliente_id IS NULL` faz com que a *query* nos devolva apenas os casos em que não há nenhum filme vinculado àquele cliente.

### Entendendo os tipos de `join`:

Vale a pena uma lida nesta pergunta para saber mais sobre *Joins*:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/)

Um join elaborado corretamente pode evitar o uso de *subqueries* em uma diversidade de ocasiões.

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar usando [NOT IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE NOT IN(
    select first_name, last_name from customer
    inner join rental on customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
);
```

Não há muito o que explicar pois o nome da função é sugestivo **not in** -> "**que não esteja em...**"

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de você fazer isso, vou demonstrar 3 aqui mas é importante levar em consideração que o uso de `subselect` ou `subquery` podem prejudicar a perfomance por isso sempre que possível opte por evitá-las.

Utilizando `NOT EXISTS` em conjunto com um `SUBSELECT`

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM custumer
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
   SELECT NULL
   FROM rental
   WHERE rental.customer_id = custumer.customer_id
   LIMIT 1
)
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b0e2/6)

Utilizando `NOT IN` em conjunto com um `SUBSELECT`

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM custumer 
WHERE custumer.customer_id NOT IN
(
   SELECT rental.customer_id
   FROM rental
   WHERE rental.customer_id = custumer.customer_id
)
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b0e2/2)

**Utilizando `LEFT JOIN` em conjunto com a condição `IS NULL`**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM custumer
LEFT JOIN rental 
   ON custumer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
WHERE rental.customer_id IS NULL;
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b0e2/1)

Comment: Sobre o `NOT EXISTS`, eu ainda poria um `LIMIT 1` para já indicar ao motor de SQL para sair na primeira linha encontrada

Comment: Inclui o `LIMIT 1` no subselect