# Selecionar itens que não contenham em uma 2ª tabela

Tags: sql, select

Preciso selecionar dados de uma tabela apenas quando o `codigo` dessa tabela não constar em uma segunda tabela. Resumidamente seria isso. Possuo a tabela `entregaitem` com as seguintes colunas `(codigo,codigoentrega,codigoestoque)` e a tabela `retorno` onde uma das colunas é `(codigoentregaitem)`. Minha necessidade é criar uma `query` que selecione todos os itens da tabela `entregaitem` quando `codigo` não existir na tabela `retorno`, Pensei em algo do tipo:

```
select * from public.entregaitem where NOT EXITS 
(select public.entregaitem.codigo, public.retorno.codigoentregaitem
from public.entregaitem,public.retorno
where public.entregaitem.codigo = public.retorno.codigoentregaitem)
```

Porém assim nada me foi retornado. Devido a existir dados onde os codigo são diferentes

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar pesquisa no MySQL que retorne linhas sem correspondência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109881/70)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, tente a seguinte consulta:

```
select * from public.entregaitem where public.entregaitem.codigoentrega not in 
(select public.retorno.codigoentregaitem from public.retorno)
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente o que precisava, assim que ficar disponível já marco tua resposta como correta, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: beleza cara, disponha! boa sorte ai.

Comment: Normalmente eu não obtenho boa performance com `not in`...

Comment: Jefferson, um left outer join também poderia ser uma solução pra este caso?

Comment: Sim, seria. Veja a resposta do CaiqueRomero. Ele deu a resposta que eu queria ter dado =]

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas formas de você fazer isso, vou demonstrar 3 aqui mas é importante levar em consideração que o uso de `subselect` ou `subquery` podem prejudicar a perfomance por isso sempre que possível opte por evitá-las.

Utilizando `NOT EXISTS` em conjunto com um `SUBSELECT`

```
SELECT item.*
FROM entregaitem AS item
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
   SELECT NULL
   FROM retorno
   WHERE retorno.codigoentregaitem = item.codigoentregaitem
)
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eec39/2)

Utilizando `NOT IN` em conjunto com um `SUBSELECT`

```
SELECT item.*
FROM entregaitem AS item
WHERE item.codigoentregaitem NOT IN
   (
   SELECT retorno.codigoentregaitem
   FROM retorno
   WHERE retorno.codigoentregaitem = item.codigoentregaitem
)
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eec39/4)

**Utilizando `LEFT JOIN` em conjunto com a condição `IS NULL`**

```
SELECT item.*
FROM entregaitem AS item
LEFT JOIN retorno 
   ON retorno.codigoentregaitem = item.codigoentregaitem
WHERE retorno.codigoentregaitem  IS NULL
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eec39/5)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda +1