# Select de valores que não estejam em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

**Meu cenario é o seguinte:**

**Tabela Fila**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tenho a tabela Atividade**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Eu preciso montar uma select, pegando os valores da tabela fila, porem preciso excluir da fila os valores que já existem na tabela atividade.
Se na tabela atividade já existir a URL 976 e USUARIO 96 , ai no select ele pularia essa linha.
Baseado na imagem, o select da fila retornaria so os IDs 975 e 973*

**Eu tentei assim, mas não deu:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM fila f
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(  
    SELECT NULL FROM atividade a 
    WHERE a.url = f.idlinks 
    AND a.usuario = f.usuario
    AND a.url = f.idlinks and a.usuario = 96
)
```

Desde já agradeço, obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar pesquisa no MySQL que retorne linhas sem correspondência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109881/como-criar-pesquisa-no-mysql-que-retorne-linhas-sem-correspond%c3%aancia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que a sua estrutura e seus dados sejam algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE fila
(
    id INTEGER,
    idlinks INTEGER,
    usuario INTEGER,
    url TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE atividade
(
    reg INTEGER,
    usuario INTEGER,
    acao INTEGER,
    datahora TIMESTAMP,
    url INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO fila ( id, idlinks, usuario, url ) VALUES ( 1, 976, 96, 'http://www.facebook.com/jesus/'  );
INSERT INTO fila ( id, idlinks, usuario, url ) VALUES ( 2, 975, 95, 'http://www.facebook.com/judas/'  );
INSERT INTO fila ( id, idlinks, usuario, url ) VALUES ( 3, 973, 93, 'http://www.facebook.com/maria/' );

INSERT INTO atividade ( reg, usuario, acao, datahora, url ) VALUES ( 3754, 96, 3, now(), 1011  );
INSERT INTO atividade ( reg, usuario, acao, datahora, url ) VALUES ( 3759, 96, 2, now(), 976  );
INSERT INTO atividade ( reg, usuario, acao, datahora, url ) VALUES ( 3760, 96, 1, now(), 988  );
```

Solução #1: `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
    f.* 
FROM
     fila AS f
LEFT JOIN
    atividade AS a ON ( a.usuario = f.usuario AND a.url = f.idlinks )
WHERE
    a.reg IS NULL AND
    f.usuario = 93;
```

Solução #2: `NOT IN`

```
SELECT
    f.* 
FROM
    fila AS f
WHERE
    f.usuario = 93 AND
    (f.idlinks, f.usuario) NOT IN (SELECT a.url, a.usuario FROM atividade AS a)
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja as soluções funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e8e2c/37)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu preciso especificar qual seria usuario que estou procurando. Se for o usuario 92, ai nao pode aparecer na fila se os links dele caso ele tenha feito interacao.

Comment: @Rene: Na sua pergunta, você exemplifica a consulta do usuário de `id = 96`, de acordo com sua lógica, como o registro desse usuário está contido em ambas as tabelas, **nenhum** registro deveria ser retornado. No seu comentário, você exemplifica o usuário de `id = 92`, que não está contido em **nenhuma** das tabelas, e seguindo a lógica da pergunta, **nenhum** registro deveria ser retornado. Segue uma edição [exemplificando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e8e2c/37) uma filtragem pelo usuário `id = 93`, que está contido apenas na tabela `Fila`.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que essa imagem irá te ajudar.

[image]